# How can I convert a float to a string, but to the sixth decimal - Python

Tags: python, floating-point, string-formatting

I need to convert a float to a string, but to the sixth decimal. How would I preform a task like that without converting it into a string with an E notation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> "{0:.6f}".format(123455.12345678)
'123455.123457'
```

Note the rounding as well.

See the python docs on [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and [format specification mini-language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Answer (score 1):

If you're on an older version of python:

```
print "%.6f" % 1.23456789
```

If you want the "e notation" you can try

```
print "%.6e" % 1.23456789
```

or

```
print "%.6E" % 1.23456789
```

Though I'm not sure now much flexibility you have with this method.